# SOLR IndexerOperationListener.afterPrepareContext(IndexerOperationListener.java:97)

Tags: indexing, solr, sap-commerce-cloud

[ImageError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96mmw.png)

I get this error when I try to fullindex in hybris (SOLR)
I have 5 identical indexes (only the range of products to be indexed changes), but for 2 of these the full indexes everything works correctly while for 3 I have this error.

The configurations of the 5 indices are the same, only the range of products to be indexed changes (I have 5 product catalogs).

The error occurs when trying to make a full of solr in hybris (example of a log for the cronjob):

22.08.12 04:49:53:119   INFO    Started indexer cronjob.
22.08.12 04:49:53:389   WARN    Error during indexer call: fmfIndex

I have a standalone configuration with two nodes one as master and one as slave and this configuration:

[BackOfficeConfig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjLTT.png)

I would like to know if it is a SOLR configuration problem on hybris or on the machines or whatever.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your errors and code as **text** rather than as a screenshot. On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.